# Как передать переменные в email шаблон?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Доброго дня!

Я работаю с CI. Хочу отправлять шаблон email сообщение, которое должно содержать в себе некоторые переменные. Сейчас я имею следующую mysql таблицу с email шаблоном:

```
ID | Title | Message |
----------------------
1  | Тема  | Текст   |
```

Я вызываю этот шаблон в контролере изменения статуса заказа клиента на сайте:

```
$user = $this->users_model->get_user_mail($verification['user']);
$email_template = $this->emailtemplate_model->get_email_template(1);

                $this -> email -> from($this->settings->site_email, $this->settings->site_name);
                $this -> email -> to($user['email']);
                $this -> email -> subject($email_template['title']);
                $this -> email -> message("$email_template['message']");
```

Файл **model**:

```
function get_email_template($id = NULL)
    {
        if ($id)
        {
            $sql = "
                SELECT *
                FROM {$this->_db}
                WHERE id = " . $this->db->escape($id) . "
            ";

            $query = $this->db->query($sql);

            if ($query->num_rows())
            {
                return $query->row_array();
            }
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
```

**Вопрос:** как передать в шаблон письма переменную $verification['user'], используя условные сокращения в шаблоне по типу "[NAME]", что бы в итоге было Text "[NAME]", где "[NAME]" - переданная переменная $verification['user'] ?

Новичок. Благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: какого уровня вы новичек? вы хоть типы данных понимаете? произвести замену $verification['user'] в текстовую Message из базы? регуляркой например.

Comment: Может быть `str_replace` достаточно?

Comment: Это решило мою проблему